# how to use instance variables in a static method

Tags: java

I have a problem going on in Java.
I'm really new to Java, so don't blame me for weird code and stuff.

I'm making a small thingymabob that randomly generates numbers and uses them to create information about a randomly generated tree that is outlined by that information.
The problem is, I need to make a static void to print the stats of the tree.

But all my variables - "treeheight", "treetrunkwidth", etc. - can't be static, or every variable piece of information reverts to 0 or null. And this is annoying, because if I make my void for printing the tree stats not static, then it doesn't show up, but if I make it static, it won't let the tree's information be randomly generated and changed at will.

What do I do??

-AndeX

Comment: First of all you should post your code... then we will see what we can do...

Comment: You want some information to be associated with Object then instantiate the object and use.

Comment: You need to show some code. But it probably boils down to having `new thingymabob()` somewhere.

Comment: You can't because it should not. static should only able to access local variable and everything that declared static.

Comment: Why does this need to be static? There is one set of stats for each thingymabob, not one for the class. To print those make `void printMe()` or better yet override `String toString()`, which every object has. Then every thingymabob can describe itself with a string.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as that

1 : static members can be accessed with class reference

```
ClassName.staticVar
```

2 : non static members can be accessed by instance reference

```
new CLassName()
```

now if you can please post your code , we can give exact suggestion

Comment: I think Andex wants to call the instance variable by not using "new".

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Instance variables are exactly that, "instances" of the object. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Thingymabob you can create

```
public static void main(String[] argsIgnored) {
    Thingymabob anInstance = new Thingymabob();
    anInstance.doStuffToSetItUp()...
    System.out.println("treeheight = " + anInstance.getTreeheight ());
    System.out.println("treetrunkwidth = " + anInstance.getTreetrunkwidth ());
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `Java Singleton Class`. I recommend you [look here for more information](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm)

It will mean that you will only ever have one instance of you class `Thingymabob` and you can access its properties as you normally would via `getters and setters`.

This is what the `constructor` and `getInstance` would look like:

```
private Thingymabob() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static Thingymabob getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Thingymabob();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

You would then access it in all your other classes like so:

```
Thingymabob thingy = Thingymabob.getInstance();
```